# Can't put header and navigation next to each other

Tags: css

I'm trying to put my navigation bar next to the header, but it's forcing the header on top of the navigation. If you don't know what I mean, this is how I want the header and navigation menu to be laid out:
[Snow Candy](http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/snowboard-design-code/demo/index.html) <-

This is the HTML that I've got:

```
<div id="header">
<h1>Logo</h1>
<ul id="nav">

<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

</ul></div>
<div id="content">
<h1>Header One</h1>
</div>
```

This is the CSS I've got:

```
body
{
background-image: url('bground.png');
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
}

#header{
float: right;
}


ul, li, a{
display: inline;
list-style: none;
font-family: arial;
color: #3C7DC4;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px;
}

li, a:hover{
display: inline;
list-style: none;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 25px;
color: #FF8F00;
}

#content{
background: #FF8F00;
max-width: 800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
border-style:solid;
border-width:10px;
border-color: #121212;
min-height: 200px;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Henry.

I added some code into the css - http://jsfiddle.net/JET4v/2/

Also added wrapper to keep it all in control.

- This basically says that there wont be anything beside `#header` and 
  `#content`
- Also `#header` `#header h1` `#header #nav` `#content` will all be
  floated to the left.
- And `#wrap` basically centers itself.

  ```
  #wrap { margin: 0 auto; width: 700px; }
  #header,
  #content{ clear: both; }

  #header,
  #header h1,
  #header #nav { float: left; }
  ```

Note that you might want to add width and height values too, but not height to the `#content` of course.

And if you want to use `#wrap` you should know that it should be the width of your widest element(s)

Comment: #header #nav { float: left; } this seems overkill, you could've just used #nav { float: left; }. #nav is unique anyway.

Comment: @Willempie Not necessarily. `float:left` is an excellent way to tell the browser where that elements Actual width and height ends. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/j43P2/

Comment: I was referring to how you specified that css rule, `#nav { float: left; }` is easier to resolve for the browser than `#header #nav { float: left; }` while maintaining the exact same visual output.

Comment: @Williempie Took me this long to understand what you meant. Though i wouldn't call it overkill as it actually has meaning. I wanted to make it easy to read. Especially for beginners this `#header #nav` should right away say that `#nav` is inside `#header`.